# How can I reverse the direction of this square after it reaches a certain value?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm trying to create an idle animation where the red rectangle moves back and forth slightly in a loop. For some reason once it reaches the specified threshhold instead of proceeding to move in the opposite direction, it just stops.

What did I do wrong?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Spaceship structure 
        var shipWidth = 250;
        var shipHeight = 100;

        // Canvas parameters
        var cWidth = canvas.width;
        var cHeight = canvas.height;

        // Positioning variables 
        var centerWidthPosition = (cWidth / 2) - (shipWidth / 2);
        var centerHeightPosition = (cHeight / 2) - (shipHeight / 2);

        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
        function drawShip(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(centerWidthPosition,centerHeightPosition,shipWidth,shipHeight);

                centerWidthPosition--;
                if (centerWidthPosition < 400){
                    ++centerWidthPosition;
                }

            requestAnimationFrame(drawShip);
        }
        drawShip();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TheAmberlamps explained why it's doing that. Here I offer you a solution to achieve what I believe you are trying to do.

Use a velocity variable that changes magnitude. X position always increases by velocity value. Velocity changes directions at screen edges.

```
// use a velocity variable
var xspeed = 1;

// always increase by velocity
centerWidthPosition += xspeed; 

// screen edges are 0 and 400 in this example
if (centerWidthPosition > 400 || centerWidthPosition < 0){ 
    xspeed *= -1; // change velocity direction
}
```

I added another condition in your if that causes the object to bounce back and forth. Remove the selection after || if you don't want it doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is caught in a loop; once centerWidthPosition reaches 399 your conditional makes it increment back up to 400, and then it decrements back to 399.

Comment: Ahhh wow I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

here is another one as a brain teaser - how would go by making this animation bounce in the loop - basically turn text into particles and then reverse back to text and reverse back to particles and back to text and so on and on and on infinitely:

```js
var random = Math.random;
window.onresize = function () {
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};
window.onresize();
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = 'bold 50px "somefont"';
ctx.textBaseline = 'center';
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
var _particles = [];
var particlesLength = 0;
var currentText = "SOMETEXT";
var createParticle = function createParticle(x, y) {_particles.push(new Particle(x, y));};
var checkAlpha = function checkAlpha(pixels, i) {return pixels[i * 4 + 3] > 0;};
var createParticles = function createParticles() {
var textSize = ctx.measureText(currentText);
ctx.fillText(currentText,Math.round((canvas.width / 2) - (textSize.width / 2)),Math.round(canvas.height / 2));
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(1, 1, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var pixels = imageData.data;
var dataLength = imageData.width * imageData.height;
for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
var currentRow = Math.floor(i / imageData.width);
var currentColumn = i - Math.floor(i / imageData.height);
if (currentRow % 2 || currentColumn % 2) continue;
if (checkAlpha(pixels, i)) {
var cy = ~~(i / imageData.width);
var cx = ~~(i - (cy * imageData.width));
createParticle(cx, cy);
}}
particlesLength = _particles.length;
};
var Point = function Point(x, y) {
this.set(x, y);
};
Point.prototype = {
set: function (x, y) {
x = x || 0;
y = y || x || 0;
this._sX = x;
this._sY = y;
this.reset();
},
add: function (point) {
this.x += point.x;
this.y += point.y;
},
multiply: function (point) {
this.x *= point.x;
this.y *= point.y;
},
reset: function () {
this.x = this._sX;
this.y = this._sY;
return this;
},
};
var FRICT = new Point(0.98);//set to 0 if no flying needed
var Particle = function Particle(x, y) {
this.startPos = new Point(x, y);
this.v = new Point();
this.a = new Point();
this.reset();
};
Particle.prototype = {
reset: function () {
this.x = this.startPos.x;
this.y = this.startPos.y;
this.life = Math.round(random() * 300);
this.isActive = true;
this.v.reset();
this.a.reset();
},
tick: function () {
if (!this.isActive) return;
this.physics();
this.checkLife();
this.draw();
return this.isActive;
},
checkLife: function () {
this.life -= 1;
this.isActive = !(this.life < 1);
},
draw: function () {
ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1);
},
physics: function () {
if (performance.now()<nextTime) return;
this.a.x = (random() - 0.5) * 0.8;
this.a.y = (random() - 0.5) * 0.8;
this.v.add(this.a);
this.v.multiply(FRICT);
this.x += this.v.x;
this.y += this.v.y;
this.x = Math.round(this.x * 10) / 10;
this.y = Math.round(this.y * 10) / 10;
}
};
var nextTime = performance.now()+3000;
createParticles();
function clearCanvas() {
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
(function clearLoop() {
clearCanvas();
requestAnimationFrame(clearLoop);
})();
(function animLoop(time) {
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
var isAlive = true;
for (var i = 0; i < particlesLength; i++) {
if (_particles[i].tick()) isAlive = true;
}
requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
})();
function resetParticles() {
for (var i = 0; i < particlesLength; i++) {
_particles[i].reset();
}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).